# Get the folder path under cursor?

Tags: c#

I'am working on my small project: Crypt container. To unlock it - just plug-in specifig usb flash-drive and unplug it to lock container.

So, GUI of program is very simple - just ListView. If you want to add files into continer - drag'n'drop items to them.

But i have a problem - when user want to decrypt his file, he drag them in container and drop to desktop (or specific folder). And my task is to know, where user wants to put a file. If he drag file to folder - i should unpack it to folder, if he drag it to flash-drive - i should unpuck it to flash-drive.

Yes, i found one solution of my problem: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/DragNDrop.aspx , but i realy not understand that mechanism with tempDirectoryWatcher and Hashtables.

Maybe somebody know easy way to get path to object (folder, drive, etc.) under cursor?

Answer (score 3):

Your data object should [expose FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR and FILECONTENTS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/03/19/8080215.aspx). The user might drop onto something other than a folder, like an email message, or into a virtual folder like an FTP site or a ZIP folder