# c# how to get window explorer Directory path under mouse cursor

Tags: c#, .net, explorer

I want to get window explorer Directory path under mouse cursor.
I tried `AutomationElement` but it only detect name or process id etc that I dont want. I
also tried `SHDocVw.ShellWindows` It seems working but I cant define which one is choosen.

here is a source i tried

```
string GetDropPath(AutomationElement element){
            string dir = element.Current.Name;

            if (dir.Split('.').Length >= 2) return null;

            string desktop = CommonDir["Desktop"];
            if (Directory.Exists(desktop + "\\" + dir))
            {
                dir = desktop + "\\" + dir;
            }
            else
            {
                if (CommonDir.ContainsKey(dir))
                {
                    dir = CommonDir[dir];
                }
                else if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                {


                    foreach (InternetExplorer item in new SHDocVw.ShellWindows())
                    {
                        //uint ppid = 0;
                        //GetWindowThreadProcessId(item.HWND, out ppid);
                        if (item.LocationURL.ToString().StartsWith("file:///"))
                        {
                            List<int> children = GetAllChildrenWindowHandles(item.HWND, 100);
                            if (item.HWND == element.Current.NativeWindowHandle || children.Contains(element.Current.NativeWindowHandle))
                            {
                                string pth = item.LocationURL.Replace("file:///", "");
                                if (Directory.Exists(pth + "\\" + dir))
                                {
                                    dir = pth + "\\" + dir;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    dir = pth;
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            if (Directory.Exists(dir))
            {
                return dir;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered in a previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869944/get-the-folder-path-under-cursor